# Bootstrap: как растянуть блок одним боком до края страницы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

народ! Сейчас верстаю лендинг на бутстрапе, и есть у меня такой вот блок который хочет вылазить одним боком за сетку. Вот он гад, красным цветом нарисован.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы левым боком он упирался в сетку, а правым боком упирался в край окна браузера?

Comment: Можете выслать ваш HTML и CSS? Так как не совсвем ясно как Вы их описуете

Comment: Вот вам код: https://codepen.io/anton-andreich-grechanyi/pen/rZvVzp . Задача в том чтобы красный блок растянуть правым боком до края окна браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как один из примеров, можно вынести красный блок за общий контейнер, и создать для него отдельный, как одно из решений (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPdXqV):

HTML:

```
<div class="container-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col red-block">
      Red block
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-2 {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 550px);
  width: calc(50% + 550px);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Да, этот способ подошел.